# Expresso Store: Empty Cart on Member Logout

Tags: expresso-store

'Empty Cart on Member Logout' seemed to be an option in an older version of Store (https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/v1/settings_general.html#empty_cart_on_member_logout) but missing on the version I have installed - v2.4.1. Is there a way to prevent the cart emptying when a user logs out? ie if a user saves items to the cart, does not purchase, logs out then back in later.